# Replace GoogleMaps API V2 with OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, blackberry, maps, openstreetmap

How can I replace GoogleMaps API V2 with OpenStreetMap?
I have an proyect that I have integrated GoogleMaps in this project but I want to replace it with OpenStreetMap

Comment: Search the OpenStreetMap docs and please ask a more concrete question. Ask for example about a specific problem you found with the new API.

Answer (score 2):

OSM itself doesn't provide an webmap functionality. OSM is a community dedicated to collect gepspatial informations and as a consequence they are also "playing" with visualizing this data to render different styled maps (but don't try to replace Google Maps itself).

So what you are asking about is a **mix of different components**:

- [Webmap toolkit](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks#Webmaps) (Leaflet became popular and easy to use, while OpenLayers is more powerful)
- (or a [native widget](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks#Widgets), Mapsforge seems to be popular on Android)
- Map [tile provider](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TMS) (OSM itself allows only minimal use for third party services)

A very good summary is also [switch2osm.org](http://www.switch2osm.org)